# Grunt set option for task and run that task using new value

Tags: javascript, html, gruntjs, build-process

I have Grunt build automation added in my project.

I have created one custom task which sets a variable for other task and now I want to run the task using the value I set.

```
grunt.registerTask('dist-flow', function () {
    if (!grunt.option('env')) {
        grunt.option('env', 'prod');
        console.log(grunt.option('env'));
    }
    grunt.registerTask('dist',['dev_prod_switch']);
    grunt.task.run('distdev');
});
```

But whenever I run the `dist-flow` task it will set `env` to `prod` but `dev_prod_switch` always take default value which I set for `dev_prod_switch`.

So I want set the options from task and run specific task using that new value.

Comment: Could you maybe clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to set the grunt option for one task from other task. whatever value we set using grunt option i have to run the task using that specific task

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Can you add what `distdev` is, and what input/output you are giving/getting and what you expect to get.

Comment: dev_prod_switch: {
            options: {
                environment: grunt.option('env') || 'dev',
                env_char: '#',
                env_block_dev: 'env:dev',
                env_block_prod: 'env:prod'
            },
            all: {
                files: {
                    'appCommon/config.js': 'appCommon/config.js',
                }
            }
        },

Comment: dev_prod_switch: { options: {
                environment: grunt.option('env') || 'dev',
                env_char: '#',
                env_block_dev: 'env:dev',
                env_block_prod: 'env:prod'
            }},
grunt.registerTask('dist-flow', 'cusotm flow', function () {
                if (!grunt.option('env') ) {grunt.option('env', 'prod');                }
                grunt.run('dev_prod_switch');})
when i run "dist-flow" i am setting the env=prod and i want "dev_prod_switch" take the prod as option and run the task

Comment: @Megha you should update your question to reflect your comments.

Answer (score 3):

## The problem:

Based on your question and comments, I'm assuming your `Gruntfile.js` looks something like this.

#### Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        dev_prod_switch: {
            options: {
                environment: grunt.option('env') || 'dev',
                env_char: '#',
                env_block_dev: 'env:dev',
                env_block_prod: 'env:prod'
            },
            all: {
                files: {
                    'appCommon/config.js': 'appCommon/config.js',
                }
            }
        },
    });

    grunt.registerTask('dist-flow', function () {
        if (!grunt.option('env') ) {
            grunt.option('env', 'prod');
            console.log(grunt.option('env'));
        }
        grunt.registerTask('dist',['dev_prod_switch']);
        grunt.task.run('distdev');
    });
};
```

Your issue is that you are trying to set the `option` inside a task, and read it back in the `initConfig` object. The trouble is, `initConfig` runs before your tasks, so `environment` has already been set to the default when your `dist-flow` task is run.

#### This line:

```
environment: grunt.option('env') || 'dev',
```

#### Runs before this line:

```
grunt.option('env', 'prod');
```

## A Solution:

Inside your task, you can access your config option through `grunt.config`, so you could modify the value in the config object like so.

```
grunt.config.data.dev_prod_switch.options.environment = grunt.option('env');
```

### Example Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        dev_prod_switch: {
            options: {
                environment: grunt.option('env') || 'dev',
                env_char: '#',
                env_block_dev: 'env:dev',
                env_block_prod: 'env:prod'
            },
            all: {
                files: {
                    'appCommon/config.js': 'appCommon/config.js',
                }
            }
        },
    });

    grunt.registerTask('dist-flow', function () {
        if (!grunt.option('env') ) {
            grunt.option('env', 'prod');
            console.log(grunt.option('env'));
            grunt.config.data.dev_prod_switch.options.environment = grunt.option('env');
            console.log(grunt.config.data.dev_prod_switch.options.environment);
        }
        grunt.registerTask('dist',['dev_prod_switch']);
        grunt.task.run('distdev');
    });
};
```